# How to access an element of an array inside of an array in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to access the first element  inside the array 'levels'.

```
unsigned char Level1[70] =
{
    0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x03,0x07,0x02,0x02,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x03,0x03,0x02,0x02,0x01,
    0x01,0x01,0x0b,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x01,0x08,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x0f,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,
    0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02
};

unsigned char (*levels)[1] = {&Level1};
```

I have tried things like:

```
unsigned char curr_level[70] = levels[0];
```

but they have not worked.

Thank you!

Comment: Huh?   I only see one array.

Comment: levels[0] is a pointer to an array, not an array.

Comment: If `70` is a meaningful number it should be a `#define` constant of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING: this answer may be INCORRECT** See comments for details.

According to your declaration,

```
unsigned char (*levels)[1] = {&Level1};
```

`levels` is an array of char pointers, and therefore `levels[0]` is a char pointer.
So depending on what you want to do, you may try one of the followings:

```
unsigned char *curr_level=levels[0];
```

or

```
unsigned char *curr_level;
curr_level=malloc(sizeof(Level1)); /* Don't forget to call free() on it later */
memcpy(curr_level,levels[0],sizeof(Level1));
```

Comment: `unsigned char (*levels)[1]` declares `levels` to be a pointer to an array of 1 `unsigned char`, not to be an array of “char pointers”. `levels[0]` is an array of 1 `unsigned char`; it is not a “char pointer”, although, in many uses, it will be converted to a pointer to its element.

Comment: @eric Thank you. Is it because of the parentheses(or would there be any difference if it is `unsigned char *levels[]`)? And according to your comment, it is actually incorrect to declare like that (since one is misusing an array as a pointer)?